# Grant Registry permissions in VBA (Excel Macro)

Tags: vba, registry

I Need to set permissions on HKLM on a specific node, using VBA

I would like to do this within an Excel VBA macro. I only found a .net class that could do this (System.Security.Permissions.RegistryPermission). However I do not know if this can be done in VBA.

I would like to grant "full Access" for the current user or an AD Group for a key.

Comment: Is VBA running as administrator? Also, ....why VBA over, say, PowerShell?

Comment: Hi, this is part of an other Project that is running as Excel VBA macro anyway. For this I want to solve this way. And I don t know if it is good idea to have a PowerShell solution and trigger it from that VBA macro

Comment: I am Aware that Excel must run with admin privileges to be able to set those permissions

Comment: Invoking a PowerShell script from VBA should be rather trivial, and you'll have a much easier time tweaking registry permissions with the .net api than going 100% VBA, although it's probably possible to do...why wouldn't PowerShell be a "good idea"?

Comment: only limitation is my not existing knowledge regarding PowerShell, I guess